# Error when sending post in Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular

Angular 2 post request showing this error.

```
do_login(username: string,password: string): Observable<string> {
    let body = JSON.stringify({"username":username,"password":password});
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(this.loginUrl, body, options)
          .map((response) => {
            return response.json();
          }
    );
}
```

Get request working fine. and POST url working fine when calling on REST client

[image]

What is missing in my code. Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of CORS. You don't handle preflighted requests on the server side. This is what the 405 status code says:

> **405 Method Not Allowed**
>   A request method is not supported for the requested resource; for example, a GET request on a form which requires data to be presented via POST, or a PUT request on a read-only resource.

It works for GET methods because you're in the case of simple requests, not preflighted ones. It's typically a server side issue not a frontend / Angular2 one.

These articles could help you to understand what happens:

- http://restlet.com/blog/2015/12/15/understanding-and-using-cors/
- http://restlet.com/blog/2016/09/27/how-to-fix-cors-problems/

Answer (score 1):

CORS is involved, as there is an `OPTIONS` request that precedes the `POST` request.

The server is not providing a valid response to the `OPTIONS` request - resulting the error you have listed above. You will need to investigate the CORS configuration of your server, as that's where to problem lies - not in the above code.

If the `GET` is working fine, you should look at the [`Access-Control-Allow-Methods`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Methods) configuration